# Help me solve this probability question.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand how to do these simple questions where one has to find probability, given pdf or cdf.

Here is the question:

[image]

This one is a cdf and from my understanding of a cdf, $P(2\le X<4)$ should be equal to $F(4)-F(2)$ which comes out to $0.25$ but answer given is $0.4$.

What am I missing?

Comment: $P(2≤X<4) =1 -P(X<2)$.  But $P(<2)=.6$ so this is $.4$.

Comment: $F(2)=1/2+2/8=0.75$????

Comment: Yes, I edited.  I assumed (without looking) that the distribution was continuous.  It isn't.  You don't want $F(2)$ you want the probability that $X<2$.  For continuous distributions this is the same, but for discrete distributions it needn't be.

Comment: why is it discrete?

Comment: Because the cdf is discontinuous.  $\lim_{x\to 2^-}F(x)=.6\neq F(2)$.  Thus there is a non zero probability that $X=2$.  Specifically, $P(X=2)=.75-.6=.15$.

Comment: @lulu ok so i get it now i guess. If cdf is discontinuos at any break points, which this one is at 1 and 2, $F(x_0)\neq P(X\le x_0)$. But in this non continuos cases how to find probablities, can you explain plz

Comment: Note:  the distribution isn't purely discrete.it is continuous between $0$ and $!$ and again from $2$ up.  But there is a non-zero probability that $X=1$ and a non-zero probability that $X=2$.

Comment: Here it's easy because you can write out the probabilities exactly.  In general, to get $P(X<2)$ you'd need to compute $\lim_{x\to 2^-}F(x)$  which might be hard if $F(x)$ is complex.  But here we can see that there is no chance that $1<X<2$ (since the cdf doesn't change in that interval) so the limit is easy to read off.

Comment: To use different words:  Since we can't have $1<X<2$, $P(X<2)=P(X≤1)=F(1)=.6$

Answer (score 0):

We can drop "$X < 4$" in $P(2 \le X < 4)$ since $F(x) = P(X \le x) = 1 \forall x \ge 3$.  (In particular, taking $x = \pi$ gives $F(\pi) = P(X \le \pi) = 1$.  Translating this into English gives "$X$ is less than or equal to $\pi$ (i.e. 4) almost surely".)  Writing the probability in the [set theoretic definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition), we have
\begin{align}
& P(X < 2) \\
=& P(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)<2\}) \\
=& \sup_{\epsilon>0} P(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\le2-\epsilon\}) \\
=& \sup_{0<\epsilon<1} P(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\le2-\epsilon\}) \\
=& \sup_{0<\epsilon<1} F(2-\epsilon) \\
=& \sup_{1<x<2} F(x) \\
=& \sup_{1<x<2} \frac35 \\
=& \frac35.
\end{align}

So $P(2\le X<4) = P(X \ge 2) = 1 - P(X>2) = 1 - \frac35 = \frac25$, which is OP's given answer.